# Why my CSS format is not working in node?

Tags: node.js

I meet some problems with my node code. So the thing is I want to create a local server on port 3000. After I link my html code which is

```
app.get("/",(req,res,next)=> {
    res.sendfile(path.join(__dirname+'/src'+'/index.html'));
})
```

my chrome browser showed that :

```
Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:3000/app.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
```

Plus, my CSS is not working. Here is the CSS tag in my HTML

```
<link href="./app.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Anyone knows how to fix it? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

To serve static files such as images, CSS files, and JavaScript files, use the express.static built-in middleware function in Express

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use(express.static('public'));
```

Read more about [Serving static files in Express](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html)

Comment: Thank you so much! Problem Solved!